# Cakephp - Auth->login() returns true but next page I'm no longer logged in

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm trying to code an SSO between Joomla and my CakePHP (1.3) app. Users should be able to log into Joomla, click a link to go to the CakePHP app and be logged in with the same user.

In my users_controller, I have an action called 'joomlalogin()' where I read the Joomla session variables, check to see whether the joomla user already exists in my CakePHP app, create the user if not. This all works.

The issue is that I can't seem to manually log the user in using Auth->login(). I tried passing a full user, tried passing the user_id. The function returns 'true' but as soon as I go to a next page, the login seems to have failed. Here's one version of the code:

```
$existing_user= $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.joomla_userid' => $joomla_user->id)));
if ($existing_user && $this->Auth->login($existing_user)) {
  $this->Session->setFlash('You have successfully logged in.');
  //debug($this->Auth);
  $this->redirect('/users');
}
```

The flash message appears, the redirect happens but it immediately gets redirected to the (regular non-sso) login form because the '/users' is not allowed for anonymous users.

Why is Auth->login() returning 'true' if the user is not really logged in. When I look at Auth->User(), it contains the correct user data, everything indicates the user is logged in until the redirect happens. Any idea what could be the cause of this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have sessions properly setup on core.php?

Comment: I already had a normal usersystem/login procedure in place (before the SSO code) which is still working normally. So the sessions must be properly set up I presume.

Comment: You should check wether the user is logged in or not. Maybe he is, but you made a mistake when giving the authorization to go /users.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Works fine on my development laptop (built-in Apache on OSX), but not on my webserver (Ubuntu). This leads me to believe it's either a permissions issue on the filesystem or a missing module. I'm not seeing any errors in the logs so I suspect the latter. What needs to be installed to make AuthComponent work?

Comment: @ALS: The user is logged in, I do that check. Going to '/users' is not a mistake, it doesn't actually go there, I just gave that as an example, changing the redirect to other pages has no different effect.

Comment: @elliot: Try changing the session handler in core.php, that may verify whether it's a file permission issue. This is not the cause of my issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of found the cause. The issue had something to do with the inclusion of the Joomla files (to access the Joomla session data & user). If I try to log the user in using a function where these files are not included, it *does* work. Some of the code that screwed it up was:

```
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
$joomla_mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$joomla_mainframe->initialise();
$joomla_session =& JFactory::getSession();
$joomla_user = $joomla_session->get('user');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Turns out the system clock running on my server VM was incorrect. I ran this command to update it.

```
ntpdate time.windows.com
```

Note that this doesn't fix the underlying problem, which is that VM's have trouble keeping accurate time due to the nature of clock cycles being halted and suspended. Talk to your server administrator for a more permanent solution. Cheers to @Olivier for the tip

Comment: For a more permanent solution you could try to setup a ntp server (that would auto-sync when the vm starts). `sudo apt-get install ntp`.

Comment: I'm not running a VM and it's a linux server. The clock on the server works fine so this doesn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check that sessions are enabled for all controllers you want to carry across user information; It's handy to put it in AppController, usually.

For example:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public $components = array('Auth', 'RequestHandler', 'Session', 'Security');

}
```

Comment: All controllers have the Session component via AppController. As said, session work perfectly for normal logins. It's only the manual login that doesn't persist.